# Using BIGNUM and vU256

Tags: ios, macos, openssl, accelerate-framework

Is there any benefit on using OpenSSL's BIGNUM over Accelerate Framework's vU256, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `iOS` in your question.  That would be a great reason to use OpenSSL bignum, since the Accelerate bignum functions are not available in iOS.

Comment: That's a very practical answer for iOS :) what about the Mac?

Comment: I would probably use something the OpenSSL stuff, simply because it's more portable.

Comment: Wouldn't Accelerate achieve better performance, using the low-level processor abilities?